# Immutible or not? Deedle frame filtering

Tags: f#, functional-programming, deedle

this question might look a little trivial, it does happen in our process as the data is not clean. I have a data frame looks like

```
let tt = Series.ofObservations[ 1=>10.0; 3=>20.0;5=> 30.0; 6=> 40.0; ]
let tt2 = Series.ofObservations[1=>  Double.NaN; 3=> 5.5; 6=>Double.NaN  ]
let tt3 = Series.ofObservations[1=> "aaa"; 3=> "bb"; 6=>"ccc" ]
let f1 = frame ["cola" => tt; "colb"=>tt2;]
f1.AddColumn("colc", tt3)

 f1.Print();;
     cola colb      colc      
1 -> 10   <missing> aaa       
3 -> 20   5.5       bb        
5 -> 30   <missing> <missing> 
6 -> 40   <missing> ccc
```

I need to filter out any row until the first row with a value in colb

```
     cola colb      colc      
3 -> 20   5.5       bb        
5 -> 30   <missing> <missing> 
6 -> 40   <missing> ccc
```

The only solution i can come up with is utilising a mutable flag which breaks the integrity of functional programming. maybe a this filtering missing head can be hidden in a library. but it still makes me wonder if i did not do it the right way.

```
let flag = ref false
let filteredF1 = f1 |> Frame.filterRows(fun k v -> 
                                  match !flag, v.TryGetAs<float>("colb") with 
                                  | false, OptionalValue.Missing -> flag := false
                                  | false, _ -> flag := true
                                  | true, _ -> ()
                                  !flag
                                  )
```

This is not really a problem of Deedle but more to do with how should immutability achieve this. Something easily achievable in Python and VBA seems to be very hard to do in F#.

In statistic calculation situation like this happens where multiple serieses have a different starting time. And after the starting point (retaining) the data point containing the missing value is important as missing value means something.

Any advice is appreciated.
cassby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my preferred way:

```
// find first index having non-null value in column b
let idx = 
  f1?colb 
  |> Series.observationsAll 
  |> Seq.skipWhile (function | (_, None) -> true | _ -> false) 
  |> Seq.head 
  |> fst;;

// slice frame
f1.Rows.[idx .. ];;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your code into a function (I modified it a little, but have not tested it at all!!)

```
let dropTil1stNonMissingB frame =
  let flag = ref false
  let kernel k v ->
    flag := !flag || v.TryGetAs<float>("colb").HasValue
    !flag
  Frame.filterRows kernel frame
```

then your code just looks purely functional:

```
let filteredF1 = f1 |> dropTil1stnonMissingB
```

As long as the use of reference is restricted to a narrow scope, it should be accepted.  Immutability is not the *final goal* of functional programming.  It's only a guiding principle to write a good code.

In fact the Deedle developers should have provided their version of `Seq.fold` for `Frame`:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353471.aspx

Then you could have used it with `(new Frame([],[]), false)` as the initial `'State`.  Roughly speaking, you should be able to translate any loops in C, Python or whatever imperative language to `fold` (aka `fold_left` or `foldl`), though it isn't necessarily the way to go.

You might as well define it as an extension method of `Frame`.

```
type Frame with
  member frame.DropTil1stNonMissingB =
    ...

let filteredF1 = f1.DropTil1stNonMissingB
```

- http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-extensions/